# Youtube API key working on localhost but not on cloudways

Tags: laravel, api, youtube, cloudways

I have developed a Laravel webpage and I am using Youtube API. When I work on my test server (localhost on my computer) the YT API works just fine. However, when I transfer it to Cloudways, it brokes and gives `Error 400 Bad Request : keyInvalid` error. How should I fix it? A new key is needed for cloudways server?

Thanks!

Comment: My money is on key being in the `.env` and you forgetting to add it in production.

Comment: It was in youtube.php, not in the .env fie. Anyway, I regenerated the key, added to both youtube.php and .env file, now it works.